# move Up and Down with key thru a list of item (Ember.js)

Tags: ember.js

what I, am trying to do is move up and down thru a list of item using my keyboard. Here is a perfect example of how to do it in jquery http://jsfiddle.net/YnpW3/2/ . I want to be able to accomplish this only using ember.js

```
   keyDown: function (e) {
         var moveDown = 40;
         var moveUp = 38;

         if(e.keyCode === moveDown || e.keyCode === moveUp){

         }
     }
```

=====UPDATE======

```
keyDown: function (event) {
         var moveDown = 40;
         var moveUp = 38;
         var key = event.keyCode;
         var filteredQuestions = this.get('controller.filteredQuestions');/*get's the questions array from the controller*/

         if(key === moveDown || key === moveUp){/*determent which key have been pushed*/
             /*all the  highlightedQuestionFound finded 
             are set to false as default*/
             var highlightedQuestionFound = false;

            for (var i=0; i<filteredQuestions.length-1; i++){/* checks for the amount of questions found*/
                var filteredQuestion = filteredQuestions[i];/* gets the amount of questions found*/

                if (filteredQuestion.get('isHighlighted')){
                    /*move the Highlighted up or down*/
                    var newIndex = (key === moveDown) ? i+1 : i-1;//ternary operator
                    filteredQuestion.set('isHighlighted', false);
                    filteredQuestions[newIndex].set('isHighlighted', true);
                    highlightedQuestionFound = true;
                }
            }
             /*if the question was found, Highlighted
                the first wuestion found*/
             if (highlightedQuestionFound == false){
                filteredQuestions[0].set('isHighlighted', true);     
             }
         }
     }
```

here is my update, but still i haven't be able to get it to work. The problem now is that when i click down highlight the first one and the last list in the div........

Comment: dc/ic-tabs use this functionality that you are looking for. https://github.com/devon-capital/dc-tabs/blob/master/addon/components/dc-tab-list.js#L94 I suggest starting there, generating some actual code that you have problems with, and then come back with a proper question.

Comment: thank you for that... I just wanted a starting point....thnak you again